# Using value of one cell in a select statement (running with sqlcmd)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql, sqlcmd

EDIT: My mistake was that I had a "go" after the first select statement and that would cause @variableName to go out of scope.

I have a bunch of queries that depend on each other and I want to use the value that's returned by the first one in another one. For example I want to use the product ID of the first query,  :

```
SELECT ProductID,
FROM mproducts 
WHERE (ProductCode='$(product)' 
    or ProductCode='$(product)' 
    or BuildSysProductCode='$(product)');
```

in the second one

```
SELECT ProductVersionID, 
FROM cb_mproductversions
WHERE ProductID=***variableName***
go
```

I looked into variables, and I've seen a few ways of storing values into variables like doing

```
DECLARE @variableName
SELECT @variableName AS productID 
FROM mproducts 
...
```

But it seems that the scope of @variableName is only the next select statement, and when I get to the ones after the one right after DECLARE it says that it's not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
DECLARE @variableName int
SELECT @variableName = productID FROM mproducts WHERE .. 

SELECT ProductVersionID
FROM cb_mproductversions
WHERE ProductID = @variableName
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that I had a "go" after the first select statement and that would cause @variableName to go out of scope.

Comment: @AryanGoharzad be aware that this would fail if the first query returns more than one `productID`.

Comment: Hmm .. nice catch. I guess I'll always have to get "top 1" since product ID's are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both queries:

```
SELECT ProductVersionID, 
FROM cb_mproductversions
WHERE ProductID IN
  (
     SELECT ProductID,
     FROM mproducts 
     WHERE (ProductCode='$(product)' or ProductCode='$(product)' or BuildSysProductCode='$(product)');
  )
```

I use the `IN` because the INNER query may return more than one `ProductID`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
SELECT ProductVersionID, 
FROM cb_mproductversions
WHERE ProductID in 
(
    SELECT ProductID,
    FROM mproducts 
    WHERE (ProductCode='$(product)' or ProductCode='$(product)' or BuildSysProductCode='$(product)')
)
```